# Selecting multiple files in Finder

Tags: applescript

In my applescript, I have a function which takes a selected file and writes its path into an xml file.  If a folder is selected, i'm able to create a list with the files contained and send that to my function.  However, if I select multiple finder items (via shift clicking), whether files or folders, I'm not able to send anything to the function.

here is the part where i get the files from the Finder

```
tell application "Finder"
  set myPath to the selection
end tell
--if multiple files selected
if (count of myPath) is greater than 1 then
    set fileList to every item of myPath
    repeat with i in fileList
        if (isDirectory(i)) then
        else
            myBigLoop(initialSuccess, i, watchFolder)
        end if
    end repeat
else if (isDirectory(myPath)) then
    submitFolder(myPath, watchFolder)
else
    set isFolder to false
    set initialSuccess to true
    myBigLoop(initialSuccess, myPath, watchFolder)
end if

on myBigLoop(initialSuccess, fileList, watchFolder)
    repeat with myPath in fileList      
        if initialSuccess then          
            tell application "Finder"
                set myFilename to myPath as alias
                set myPath to the folder of myFilename              
                set myPath to myPath as string
                set myFilename to name of myFilename
                display dialog myFilename
            end tell
        end if --end InitialSuccess
    end repeat
end myBigLoop

on isDirectory(someItem) -- someItem is a file reference
    set filePosixPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (someItem as alias))
    set fileType to (do shell script "file -b " & filePosixPath)
    if fileType ends with "directory" then return true
    return false
end isDirectory

on submitFolder(myPath, watchFolder)
    set isFolder to true
    set initialSuccess to true
    set fileList to item 1 of myPath
    set fileList to get every file of fileList
    set numFiles to count fileList
    if numFiles is equal to 0 then
        display dialog "There were no files in that folder."
        return false
    end if
    myBigLoop(initialSuccess, fileList, watchFolder)
end submitFolder
```

Comment: Please include your handlers as well.

Comment: Ok I added them. @adayzdone

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should extend the Finder tell structure, because you're still working with files and folders later on:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myPath to the selection
  --if multiple files selected
    if (count of myPath) is greater than 1 then
        set fileList to every item of myPath
        repeat with i in fileList
            if (isDirectory(i)) then
            else
                myBigLoop(initialSuccess, i, watchFolder)
            end if
        end repeat
    else if (isDirectory(myPath)) then
        submitFolder(myPath, watchFolder)
    else
        set isFolder to false
        set initialSuccess to true
        myBigLoop(initialSuccess, myPath, watchFolder)
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, but I get the same behavior extending the tell.  The error is "can't make into the expected type".  I tried `set i to i as alias` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry @gneek I'll look into if no one else posts a good answer before me.